# showing an image in Angular 5 that have been send from back-end

Tags: angular

I'm working on a MEAN Stack app and what i want to do is showing the profile image of user in an image tag in `HTML5`, so the images are saved in `MongoDB` and the back-end is `Node`

This is the Node code :

```
router.get('/getProfileImageok',(req,res)=>{
    gfs.files.findOne({ metadata: req.de },(err,file)=>{
      if(!file || file.length === 0){
        res.json({success:false,message:'no file exits'});
        console.log(req);
      }
      if(file.contentType === 'image/jpg' ||file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png'){
        const readStream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
        readStream.pipe(res);
        console.log(req.decoded.userId);
      }else{
        res.json({success:false,message:'no image type'});
      }
    });
  });
```

This is the code in Angular 5 in `**service.ts**`

```
getProfileImage(){
this.createAuthenticationHeaders(); // Create headers before sending to API
 this._http.get.(this.domain + '/authentication/getProfileImageok',this.options);
}
```

This is the code in Angular 5

```
    image;
imageToShow="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/503935e6e4b011773393f0f9/t/52934b61e4b023ca75614a20/1385384808083/Facebook+User.gif";
        getImageFromService() {
              this.authService.getProfileImage().subscribe(data => {
                 this.image = data.arrayBuffer();
              }, error => {
                this.isImageLoading = false;
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
```

The code in HTML

```
  <img [src]="imageToShow || image" alt="" class="img">
```

`

after i change the code i used chrome devtool

[the is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doQPw.png)

Comment: What is the value of the `this.image`. Can you add that to the question

Comment: What is your actual question? Does anything not work as expected?

Comment: The back-end works great but the problem is the Angular it self

Comment: What exactly is `imageToShow`?

Comment: At the moment, plenty of things could be wrong in your code that looks correct. If you want accurate help, we need to understand at what points it's going wrong. If you are sure back-end is OK, you should remove that part. To me, the thing that's missing is what did angular put in your DOM to display the image?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is after the back-end send that image as respond i want to save it in a variable then show it in the DOM

Comment: My point is that you should only have code related to your issue. Just go step by step. If you remove the logic related to "imageToShow" wich looks like a placeholder if a user don't have a picture, is it still not working?

Comment: At the moment, I'm not sure the thing you are doing in `[src]="imageToShow || image"` can work. Also, I don't think that displaying an image will work without calling the DomSanitizer. Plenty of things can go wrong in your code. We don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: i tried `getProfileImage(){
  this.authService.createAuthenticationHeaders();
  this.http.get(this.authService.domain+'/authentication/getProfileImageok',this.authService.options).subscribe(
    data  => {
        this.imageToShow = data;
        //console.log((data.toString()));
        //console.log((this.imageToShow.toString()));
    },
    err => console.log('Error is..:' + err)
    );
}` in the `component.ts` to see what is the problem

Comment: and this is the result ` WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://localhost:8080/authentication/getProfileImageok (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`

Comment: `GET unsafe:Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://localhost:8080/authentication/getProfileImageok 0 ()`

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like:

```
const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        this.imageToShow = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(imgReturnedFromBackend);
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Comment: `getProfileImage(){
  this.authService.createAuthenticationHeaders();
  this.http.get(this.authService.domain+'/authentication/getProfileImageok',this.authService.options).subscribe(
    data  => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        this.imageToShow = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.imageToShow);
    },
    err => console.log('Error is..:' + err)
    );
}`

Comment: I think that the problem is that it need to convert to blob first

Comment: instead readAsDataURL try to use readAsArrayBuffer, if still not work, don't know

Comment: it's the same error  so can you write a full code for me to show me all the steps

Comment: i use it like you, but i have diffrent backend, i hoped that works also for you, can't help, sorry